# How to get details about an error from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have a function that makes a request to an XML page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "results.xml",
    error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
});
```

The request fails with the error message "error". How do I get more details about why it failed?

Comment: If you don't need the error messages for you app, but just for debugging, the best approach would be to use the Network tab on Chrome Dev Tools and see what happens with the request.

Comment: `textStatus` is supposed to give the reason of the error. `error` is deprecated. use `fail()` instead

Comment: All textStatus gives is "error"...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open things like firebug console or some other staff. There you schould see what is a problem since you have console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); this will be written in a console which I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I always have firebug open and it gives no errors. Basically, I get nothing if I don't console.log the error in the Ajax request. And all the Ajax requests seems to return is "error". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had that briefly. In firebug network tab if you don't see your called url appearing add "return false;" to stop your form from submitting normally (since you'll do it with Ajax).

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldName" value="" />
<input value="Save" id="saveButton" type="submit">
<br /><span class="show_error"></span>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
    processForm();  // do Ajax stuff
    **return false;**   // stop normal form submission so you can do it with Ajax. 
    });

   function processForm(){ 
     var fieldName = $('input[name="fieldName"]').val();
     var request = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajaxhandler.php",
     data: { fieldName: fieldName},
     dataType: "json" //Type of response to expect from server
     });
     request.done(function (msg){
     console.log("Worked");
     });
     request.fail(function (textStatus){
    $('.show_error').fadeIn(1000).html(textStatus); 
    console.error("Failed: "+ textStatus);
    });
    }

});
```

Then look at the Response tab for your ajax submitted url (in my case a php file) and make sure it is returning something (in my case json encoded success or fail message). If it doesn't return anything you'll just have an error that says 'error'.

Why is nothing returned and why can't I get any error detail? It turns out I was loading my jQuery from a different server than my own without specifying https when I was using port 443 for my ajax call.

Changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> was the fix for me.
```